# asp.net c# regex n "\n"s plus space to two "\n"

Tags: c#, regex

Can any one help me write a regular expression?  Let a string merge "/n  /n  /n" to "/n/n"

For example:

```
"abc   \n\n   \n \n    \n   \n   \n   \n   ddfdfd" === "abc   \n\n  ddfdfd"
```

So only remove the space between "\n"s.

Comment: Get [cracking](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do it.

```
string s = "abc   \n\n   \n \n    \n   \n   \n   \n   ddfdfd";

string s2 = Regex.Replace(s, @"\n\s*\n", "\n\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use a replace method, replacing matches of an expression with a string.

It sounds like you want to match `\n[\s]*\n`, and replace it with simply `\n\n`.

Comment: Isn't the character class a bit redundant?